# How to receive only the specifier value type and printing an appropriate message when not?

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf, invalid-characters

```
scanf("%x", &hexa_decimal_num);
```

I am trying to deal with the case of entering something wrong like "ZZ" and printing "Error!".

Comment: Read up on `scanf` and its return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = scanf("%x", &hexa_decimal_num);

    if (x == 0)
    {
        printf ("Error!");
    }
```

Comment: `EOF` should be taken into account too.

Comment: This would be improved with some comments and explanation about why it works.